Interface micro SD card with MCU and USB port at the same time
I'm designing a PCB and I would like an MCU (ESP32-S3) to be able to write periodically on a micro SD card (logs). I'm using SPI. I also would like to be able to get those logs through a USB port on the PCB. I found the MAX14502 from Analog Devices. This IC seems to be able to do everything I want but the chip is difficult to source and pretty old. As I'm a junior PCB designer, I'm looking for a simple but robust solution.
The MAX14502 has two modes of operation: Pass Thru and Card Reader. In pass thru, the SD and USB signals pass through the MAX14502 without modification, appearing like the device is not present. In Card Reader mode, the MAX14502 implements a high-speed USB card reader that operates independently of the host microprocessor.
So, I think there are two ways:

A bridge IC to interface the micro SD card and the USB port and a multiplexer to also be able to write on the micro SD card with the MCU (I don't know how to implement this solution and I'm afraid it will be too complicated for me)
An IC like the MAX14502 that pack all these functions

Do you know an IC that could suit my needs ? Could you provide some schematics to guide me through the process of finding the proper solution ?

That chip indeed seems to be a bit overkill. You don't need two SD interfaces, and you don't need the pass-through at all.
There's two options, the way I see it:

you don't buy any extra hardware, but use the ESP32-S3 as USB mass storage device. This means you write the firmware (modify examples) to expose the data on the SD card as USB mass storage device.
you buy a simple SD-USB converter IC, and a simple bus switch IC which, depending on whether you connect an external USB host or not, switches the SD data lines between your ESP32 and the USB converter
alternatively, potentially easier, since lower pin count: you attach the SD card / USB converter to a USB bus switch, and either connect it to your ESP32 or to an external connector, as your ESP32 can also act as USB host.


I already implemented the first solution you advised, it works well but I would like to explore other options (hardware).
About the second solution, do you think the MAX14779 could suit my needs as a switch for this solution ?

No, it's really overkill for your application and overcomplicates everything, compared to a simple 6 port bus switch and a diode for VCC

Ok, do you have one reference in mind ? I'm not familiar with bus switches

https://www.digikey.de/en/products/filter/interface/analog-switches-multiplexers-demultiplexers/747?s=N4IgjCBcoEwAwE4AsVQGMoDMCGAbAzgKYA0IA9lANogBsIpAHPeHCALqkAOALlCAJIA7boQDmhAE4gAvqQC0MVCAyRuEgK4lyVEAFZmCdtONA , or piece it together from multiple "fewer contacts" ICs. It's not like you need to switch over millions of times per second.
